# Add PYPI Package to Distribution

Tags: python, pip, shared-libraries, pypi, requirements.txt

Just a heads up that this may be an obvious question. I'm writing a package that will be generally distributed and I don't want to have to do any support in the future (don't ask). It relies on python's standard library with one exception. If that one exception gets removed from PYPI in the future, I don't want to have to update my code.

So my question is: can I include the package I downloaded from PYPI within my package so it always exists in its current state and users don't have to download it separately? If so do I just move the package from my sys.path to my package?

Thank you, and sorry if it's an obvious question.

Comment: Yes. But why not simply specify the package version if you can?

Answer (score 1):

In short - yes, you can. However it's not particularly necessary because pip supports [specifying the needed version](https://packaging.python.org/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/) in the `setup.py` and it will take care of the installation of the package.

Comment: So the "install_requires" key is a simpler version of a requirements file that can be used for a single project? I can specify the version, but what if they remove the entire project from PYPI? Thanks

Comment: Pip will only remove the package you specify, not the package that was required unless you [explicitly tell it to do so](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_uninstall/)

Comment: I mean like what if the people who wrote package X and deployed it on PyPI decide to remove it completely from PYPI.